# How to prevent preloaded apps from being reinstalled when creating new user?

Tags: windows-8, acer-aspire, bloatware

I am running Windows 8.1 (SL with Bing edition) on an Acer Aspire ES1 netbook. Acer preloads several apps on this netbook (e.g. WildTangent games, Pokki start menu), which is fine. I can remove them. After all, it was cheap, had preloaded Windows, and they need to get some money somehow.

However, what really bothers me is when I create a new user (or in this case, reactivate the Administrator user), some applications show up again in the Start screen of the new user. Even worse, Pokki start menu which I uninstalled from the Control Panel somehow gets reinstalled (and reappears in the Control Panel's uninstall list).

Where is this preinstallation of apps for new users done and is there some way I can configure what apps get preinstalled?

Comment: [Update the default user profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825135.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: @Ramhound is there no way to customize it after the installation? I did some research from the link you gave and I can see some preloaded Windows Store apps in the `Get-AppxProvisionedPackage` output so maybe I can fix that there. The start menu is not a Windows Store app though, and I don't know where that is installed from.

Comment: Windows 8.1 does not have a Start Menu, it has a Start Screen, but how you customized it is identical to how you customize the Start Menu in Windows 7.  As for your question,. there is [a way though](http://stealthpuppy.com/customize-the-windows-default-profile/), I would try it.

Comment: @Ramhound my apologies. I was referring to the "Pokki start menu" app which magically reinstalled itself when I activated the Administrator user. That does not seem to be in the list of Appx Provisioned Packages.

Comment: That will take a little more research.  Update your question to be specific.

Comment: @Ramhound after research and testing, I can confirm that removing the appx provisioned packages removes the app from a new user's start screen. I removed the Pokki start menu app by first running its uninstaller as admin from `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Pokki\Uninstall.exe` and then loading the default user's hive in regedit and removing any mentions of it there (didn't take notes for this). After doing this, it is not reinstalled for a new user. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: Sounds like you have enough information to post an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much of an answer, but...

For the preloaded Modern UI apps on the start screen, they are "Appx provisioned packages". They can be manipulated using PowerShell (administrator access recommended). List them using:

`Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online`

Take note of the "Package Name" and remove them using:

`Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName ...`

For the Pokki start menu app:

I removed the Pokki start menu app by first running its uninstaller as admin from `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Pokki\Uninstall.exe` and then loading the default user's hive in regedit and removing any mentions of it there (didn't take notes for this).